# For any set $A$ and definable class function $f$ there is a set $A'$ containing $A$ that is closed under $f$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-theory

The problem is to prove in ZF that for any set $A$ and any definable class function $f$, there is a set $A'$ containing $A$ with $im(f\restriction_{A'})\subset A'$. The way it's stated (with definable class functions) suggests that the axiom schema of replacement is involved. Just taking $A'$ to be $im(f)$ doesn't work because it doesn't necessarily contain $A$. Another option I was thinking about is to consider, for each $a$, the collection of $a, f(a), ff(a), fff(a), \dots$ and take the union over all $a\in A$. Then the union will contain $A$, and the image of the union under $f$ will be a subset of the union because the image of the union is the union of the image. But how is replacement used in this proof? Maybe it should be used to prove that the collection of $a, f(a), ff(a),\dots $ is a set? The image of $f$ is a set, and this collection, being a subset of the image of $f$ (together with the element $a$), is itself a set. Is this right?

Comment: Just some comments on your attempt, to complement my answer: Yes, how do you know that $X_a = \{a,f(a),ff(a),fff(a),\dots\}$ is a set? Your suggestion is that $X_a$ is a subset of the image of $f$. But the axiom of replacement does not tell us that the image of $f$ is a set (since $f$ is defined on the whole universe)! It tells us that the image $f(B)$ is a set for any set $B$. And there's not an obvious candidate set $B$ such that $X_a\subseteq f(B)$. Instead, you could define the function $g_a$ on $\omega$: $g_a(n) = f^n(a)$ by recursion. Then by replacement, $X_a = g_a(\omega)$ is a set.

Comment: Now you want to take  $A'$ to be $\bigcup_{a\in A}X_a$. To apply the axiom of union to form this set, you need to know that $\{X_a\mid a\in A\}$ is a set. How do you know this is a set? Well, you'd have to apply replacement again, this time to the definable class function $a\mapsto X_a$ (which is definable because you can check that the construction of $X_a$ from $a$ above was uniform in the parameter $a$). All this works, but I think the approach in my answer is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Informally first: Define $A_0 = A$ and $A_{n+1} = \mathrm{im}(f{\restriction}_{A_n})$. Let $A' = \bigcup_{n\in \omega} A_n$.

Can you show that this $A'$ works?

Now try to formalize this argument in ZF. Additional hints in the spoiler block below.

> First use the recursion theorem for $\omega$ to obtain the definable class function $g\colon n\mapsto A_n$. Then use the axiom of replacement on $g$ to prove $\{A_n\mid n\in \omega\}$ is a set. Finally, use the axiom of union to prove $A'$ is a set.